# Azure Update Management Center

Tags: azure-automation, azure-update-management-center

What is **Azure Update Management Center**?
Does it depend on any other Azure services?
How much does it cost? Do we have its details in pricing calculator?
Need to know more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Got to find the public documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/update-center/

Its not dependent on Azure Automation or Azure Monitor Logs.

Now its free as its in preview. A pricing model will be introduced when it becomes generally available.

Answer (score 0):

Any info, if the policies are working properly already? I cannot get them to work in any way with Update Management Center: https://serverfault.com/questions/1108077/azure-update-management-center-preview-policies-not-working

Comment: Hi, Apologies for the delayed response here. I have shared the feedback with product team regarding gap between policy and other issues with with registering preview UM features, status check of UM settings through portal. I will update back as I hear from the product team.